# Use sugarss with nuxt 2

Tags: webpack, postcss, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use the postcss [sugarss syntax](https://github.com/postcss/sugarss) in my nuxt project.

I've tried a variety of things:

#### Pushing a special `sss` rule to `config.module.rules` (this is what I'd prefer).

Here's basically what I've been trying in `nuxt.config.ts` and `build.extend`:

```js
// earlier on at the top level I have this
css: [ '@/assets/css/main.sss' ],

extend(config) {
    config.module = config.module || { rules: [] }
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.sss$/,
        use: [
            // 'vue-loader',
            // 'style-loader',
            // { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
            'postcss-loader?parser=sugarss',
        ]
    })
}
```

This example (with only the `postcss-loader` actually engaged) doesn't successfully add styles to the rendered page. So for example with these files:

```css
/* tailwind.css */
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

```
// main.sss
@import './tailwind.css'

a
    color: green
```

the links aren't green and none of the tailwind utilities work.

I know nuxt is *processing* those files, because if I make syntax errors in them the build fails.

Uncommenting any of those other loaders also doesn't help in any combination I've tried, but I'll admit I'm just shooting in the dark.

I'm fairly confident that the problem with this approach is that I'm not properly hooking into the nuxt webpack style loader chain, but I'm not sure how to do that. I looked at this [boilerplate example from JGJP](https://github.com/JGJP/nuxt-boilerplate), but he's using a version of nuxt 1.0, and the `'nuxt/lib/builder/webpack/style-loader.js'` file he's importing no longer exists. Nuxt has some similar concepts in `packages/webpack/src/utils/style-loader.js`, but I couldn't import those, and besides I'm not even sure that would help.

I also can't find any examples of people adding non-standard stylesheet syntaxes to nuxt.

#### Setting my `build.postcss.parser` to `sugarss`, which causes all the *normal* css in places like the `.nuxt` directory to break.

```sh
ERROR  in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError
(157:16) Unnecessary curly bracket

  155 | 
  156 | 
> 157 | .nuxt-progress {
      |                ^
  158 |   position: fixed;
  159 |   top: 0px;
```

#### Adding a special `postcss.config.js` file to my `src` directory with the `parser` set to `sugarss`, so that only *my* css files would be parsed that way. But that doesn't work, I *still* get the `.nuxt` errors described above, as well as these warnings:

```sh
WARN  Please use build.postcss in your nuxt.config.js instead of an external config file. Support for such files will be removed in Nuxt 3 as they remove all defaults set by Nuxt and can cause severe problems with features like alias resolving inside your CSS.

WARN  You did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
```

The second warning doesn't make a ton of sense, since neither the `nuxt.build.postcss` config nor the special directory config were empty.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by `console.log`ing the existing `config.module.rules` passed in to `extend(config)`, and shamelessly copying it. Here's the solution I ended up with.

```
const vueStyle = { loader: 'vue-style-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
const css = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2,
        exportOnlyLocals: false
    }
}
const postcss = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        parser: 'sugarss',
        sourceMap: true,
        plugins,
        order: 'presetEnvAndCssnanoLast'
    }
}
const cssModule = {
    ...css,
    options: {
        ...css.options,
        localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
        modules: true,
    },
}

config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.sss$/,
    oneOf: [
        { resourceQuery: /module/, use: [vueStyle, cssModule, postcss] },
        { use: [vueStyle, css, postcss] },
    ],
})
```

Comment: Hi, I'm JGJP from the GH issue you linked to in your question. Does your solution allow writing SugarSS in .vue files? If so, what are you writing in the lang attribute? Thanks

Comment: Yes it does! I have one file in particular I'm looking at that has about what you would expect: `<style lang="sss">`. (my syntax highlighting doesn't work correctly, but I just switch it to `<style lang="sass">` when I'm actually trying to work with it, and that's close enough)

Comment: Great! The reason I ask is that I came up with a different solution to this issue, yours seems to be better though so I'll switch to yours and hopefully I can update the Sublime Text syntax highlighting package to recognize lang="sss"

Comment: Do you think you could post a working boilerplate? It's not interpreting my sss files or my modules as Sugarss